# Is Guru-Shishya relation carry forward across multiple births?

Tags: atma, guru, rebirth, shishya

Rebirth, a major tenet of Hinduism, is when the soul, which is seen as eternal and part of a spiritual realm, returns to the physical realm in a new body.

There are multiple mentions of rebirth in Hinduism, including below Bhagvad Gita shloka,

> वासांसि जीर्णानि यथा विहाय
>
> नवानि गृह्णाति नरोऽपराणि।
>
> तथा शरीराणि विहाय जीर्णा
>
> न्यन्यानि संयाति नवानि देही
>
> As, after casting away worn out garments, a man later takes new ones.
>   So after casting away worn out bodies, the embodied Self encounters
>   other new ones

So lets say in one birth one soul makes one person a Guru. Does this relation of Guru-Shishya carry forward for both of the souls when they take rebirth? Or in next birth the soul may get a different soul as Guru?

Is this relationship details mentioned in any Hinduism scriptures?